# bash combine lines with KEY at beginning of second line

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

The source is a text file. There are lines that start with KEY, in that case the objective is that line is combined with the line preceding it. There are also cases where not KEY is present. In that case the line is transferred with out change to the output There is no pattern to either the unmatched strings or the 'line pairs', they each may occur individually or in groups of 2 or more lines.

Example of input text file:

```
1234 abc 
abcdef
abcdef1
KEY xyx
any arbitrary string not starting with KEY 
def 987
```

The objective is to combine the 'line pairs' into a single line while leaving the lines that do not meet the criteria unaltered.

Desired output

```
1234 abc 
abcdef
abcdef1KEY xyx
any arbitrary string not starting with KEY 
def 987
```

There are solutions where the KEY is in the first line of a 'line pair'. The preferred solutions are sed, perl, and awk in that order. However a higher preference is a solution!

Comment: Description sounds complicated...better to provide more info. Replace strings with real data and advise possible output . Solution could be as simple as `grep -A 2 "KEY" file` - find key and get two following lines. But is  it so simple what you want? I suspect not. Give a better description.

Comment: I think you mean that you want to join 2 lines when the second line starts with KEY.

Comment: @WalterA If it is like this , does he means `grep -B 1 "KEY" file` ...?

Comment: The grep -B 1 "KEY" option does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all, so this would be a completely inappropriate task for sed.

This will work on all UNIX installations with no need to install non-standard tools like perl:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^KEY/ ? OFS : ors), $0; ors=ORS} END{print ""}' file
...
string
string KEY string
string
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (awk script)?

```
BEGIN {previous=""}
/^[[:alnum:]]+$/ {if (previous) {print previous} previous=$0}
/ / {print previous, $0; previous=""}
END {if (previous) {print previous}}
```

I was assuming here that (a) the lines with KEY are always preceded by at least one line without KEY and (b) a line with a KEY is a line with a space character in it.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, where is the conditional KEY coded? Yes, there are never 2 KEY lines in a row. All lines have at least one space character.

Comment: I didn't know how your KEY input looked like, whether it was the actual string 'KEY' or just about anything separated by a space from the subsequent string. So I assumed the more general second. The third rule (in the edited version of the entire awk script) catches lines with a space in them, and whatever precedes them is the KEY.